# How to specify column names in cross apply join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I want to know how do we mention column name in Cross Apply Join and specify table name

Already Working Query:

```
select v.*, left(v.dir, charindex('/', v.dir) - 1) as dirname
from (values ('/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2') ) t(path) cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.path, 1, len(t.path) - charindex(reverse('Directory_'), reverse(t.path)) + 1, ''))) v(dir)
```

Expected Query:

```
select v.*, left(v.dir, charindex('/', v.dir) - 1) as dirname
from (values (“ColumnName”) ) t(path) cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.path, 1, len(t.path) - charindex(reverse('Directory_'), reverse(t.path)) + 1, ''))) v(dir) from table name
```

Comment: Which database system do you use? Oracle? SQL Server? Postgres? And could you please reduce the example code to the absolute minimum?

Comment: Add sample data with your expected output.

Comment: I want to fetch out the result of the name of the last Directory '/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2' i.e C and it is coming as expected with Working Query mentioned above. But I have a requirement in which I need to this for a particular column of a table

Answer (score 0):

It's will work for you

```
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(100)='/Directory_A/Directory_B/Directory_C/Folder1/Folder2'

SELECT SUBSTRING( @path,LEN(@path)-LEN(SUBSTRING(@path,PATINDEX('%folder%',@path), 100))-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the table reference:

```
select v.*, left(v.dir, charindex('/', v.dir) - 1) as dirname
from <tablename> tab cross apply
     (values (tab.ColumnName) ) t(path) cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.path, 1, len(t.path) - charindex(reverse('Directory_'), reverse(t.path)) + 1, ''))) v(dir) from table name
```